# How to reduce memory usage for processing many images?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, bitmap

I am working on a C# WPF application which uses pixel data from many images to process one image.

1. It requires the user to open multiple images of any format.
2. These images are stored using **System.Drawing.Bitmap** class in memory using **LockBits()** method and their memory addresses for the first pixel datas are stored in a **byte***.
3. New **System.Drawing.Bitmap** is created and processed using **LockBits()** method and direct memory access in **unsafe** context with **System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel** class, and its pixel values are calculated using the pixel values of all opened images for each pixel and saved to memory.
4. Processed **System.Drawing.Bitmap** is encoded to jpeg and saved into the selected location.
5. **Dispose()**, **UnlockBits()** and **GC.Collect()** methods are called.

The problem is that with the above method, all opened images must stay in the memory until the whole operation is completed.
For example, if I open 50 images with a resolution of 4160x3120, it takes up 4160*3120*3*50 bytes: about 1857 megabytes of memory.

Is there any possible solution that does not require all images to be in memory, or any other solution to reduce memory usage?

Comment: i recently read an article that you can set the fps refresh rate of controls in wpf, which can improve the performance. Maybe looking into that direction might help. Heres the link:  http://www.wpftutorial.net/FrameRate.html

Comment: If you really need all that information at once, you must store it, there's no choice. What you may be able to do, depending on your algorithm, is to share some data between memory and disk, but all the data must be in memory at some point.

Comment: "Is there any possible solution that does not require all images to be in memory". Certainly, if the image processing could be done sequentially. That is however hard to tell from your question, as you haven't told us exactly what the processing does.

Comment: Are you creating the `Bitmap` objects before you start the threads or within the threads?  That makes a significant difference.  For instance, if you're creating and locking them before you start the threads and you queue up 50 separate tasks, you will have 50 `Bitmap`s' worth of data in memory at once, waiting to be processed a few at a time depending on your processor count.  If, instead, you just pass a path to each task and let each task instantiate and lock its own `Bitmap`, you have maybe 1-8 images' worth of data in memory at once (again, depending on your processor count).

Comment: @rwank It has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: @Mephy and Clemens Thank you, you have really helped me.

Comment: @adv12 I am creating them before I start the threads, I do not have other choice, because calculation of every new pixel value needs the relative pixel values from all opened images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a C# WPF application which uses pixel data from many images to process one image.

If you need pixel data from many images then you need them in memory.  You can't process pixels directly from or to disk.  Your approach should be to minimize to only those images required.

If pixel processing is from same relative location then maybe break the image into sections (e.g. quarters).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think the direct answer for your question is no.

If you need to process all images data at run time, you need to have all of them in memory. This situation is very common in certain kind of applications that use medical images or image processing algorithms for 3D rendering, pattern recognition, etc., that's why this kind of systems usually require great hardware to run.

You are doing the right thing working in an unsafe context and you should use as much as you can the TPL (Task Parallel Library).

More performance depends of what your algorithms allow you to do.